# Не могу понять принцип работы кода

Tags: python

Не понимаю как работает этот код:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x > 0:
    if y > 0:
        print('Первая четверть')
    else:
        print('Четвертая четверть')
else:
    if y > 0:
        print('Вторая четверть')
    else:
        print('Третья четверть')
```

Этот код решает ту же задачу, но его я понимаю, а первый нет:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())

if x > 0 and y > 0:
    print('1 четверть')
if x < 0 and y > 0:
    print('2 четверть')
if x < 0 and y < 0:
    print('3 четверть')
if x > 0 and y < 0:
    print('4 четверть')
```

Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: На самом деле не совсем ту же задачу, второй код не берёт случаи, когда координата попадает на ось

Comment: Ну возьмите 4 варианта x,y = -1,-1; -1,1; 1,-1; 1,1 и пройдитесь по коду выполняя его "вручную" для каждого из вариантов. И всё поймёте.

Comment: Благодарю покорно

Answer (score 0):

Первый код не совсем верен. В случае, если x > 0, действительно это будет либо I, либо IV четверть. При y > 0 - I четверть, все верно. Однако, условие ***иначе*** сработает при y <= 0 и код выдаст IV четверть, что не верно для y = 0.
Для x = 0 ситуация аналогична.